# Properly mix QGraphicItems and CGAL

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, generic-programming, cgal

I have some `QGraphicsItem` (mainly `QGraphicsTextItems`) in a `QGraphicsScene`.

I now want to distribute these item in different ways according to their bounding boxes and positions. For all my algorithms I would like to use *CGAL* and decouple them completely from the presentation (*Qt*). The reason for this is to be able to quickly switch frontends while keeping the actual algorithms intact.

I can get a bounding box from a `QGraphicsItem` by

```
QrectF bb = item->boundingRect();
```

which can be converted to a `CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<Kernel>` using the CGAL Qt converter.

So far my function signature for the algorithm looks like this:

```
namespace Backend {

template<typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
OutputIt distribute(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt result);

}
```

In the frontend I have:

```
std::vector<QGraphicsTextItem*> items = { 
    addText("gHello"),
    addText("gWorld"),
    addText("g42") };

distribute(begin(items), end(items), back_inserter(output));
```

My idea was to extend my original signature with a function that would extract the bounding box like this:

```
namespace Backend {

template<typename InputIt, typename OutputIt, typename BoundingBox>
OutputIt distribute(InputIt first,
                    InputIt last,
                    OutputIt result,
                    BoundingBox bbox)
{
    // ...
    CGAL::Iso_rectangle_2<Kernel> bb = bbox(*first);
    // ...
}

}
```

However this still leaves me with the problem of updating the `QGraphicsItems` positions afterwards. How can such a generic algorithm be designed, in order to decouple it from the presentation?

**UPDATE**

Right now the stuff distribute does is really simple manipulation and transformation of rectangles. However, the goal is to produce different versions of distribute which could, for example include sweepline or force based approaches approaches. One key point is to preventing an overlap of the different bounding boxes.

Comment: The wonderful thing about CGAL is that everything is generic. All you need is to provide your own implementation (model) of whatever concepts the `Iso_rectangle_2` implements, and simply provide it to CGAL. The `distribute` function should know nothing about your particular use: just feed it the rectangles that hold the handle to a `QGraphicsItem` and move them as they themselves are modified. This is explained nicely in the *CGAL Arrangements* book.

Comment: Whether you need to make your own kernel that provides your model of the `IsoRectangle_2` concept depends on what `distribute` does, so it'd be of great help if you could update the question with the code of `distribute`, or at least a full list of all the CGAL concepts it uses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and the recommendation of the *CGAL Arrangements* book. I am figuring that you mean the manual on Arrangements? I have updated the initial question to add some perspective. As you can see, I am still in the concept phase - my goal is to get the basic viewer up and then start to implement the algorithms.

Comment: It's a very nice book published by Springer. Not free, but worth it IMHO.

Comment: A big question is then: do you really need CGAL? CGAL is great if you need exact predicates, for example. Here: do you care about where the objects intersect, or if they do intersect? It seems to me that there won't be much of a benefit from CGAL on distributions, not unless you will want to somehow control their topology iff the object are touching (touching is not overlap - did you mean merely lack of overlap or no touching?).

Comment: My goal is to produce an automatic labeling of contents of an SVG, where text is connect to parts of the SVG via lines (leaders). One generally wants to reduce for example the number of intersection points. Some approaches depend on finding these intersection points (exactly) and then rewiring the leaders. However most of the time one can asume that 2 points don't share the same x or y coordinate. In the future I will also want to compute things like the convex hull of the SVG graphics.

Comment: Well, then you definitely want CGAL.